# Using CountVectorizer in Python Mapper Reducer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tokenize, mapper, reducers

I am trying to apply tokenizer using python mapper reducer function. I have following code but I keep getting error. reducer outputs values in a list and I am passing values to the vectorizer.

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

class bagOfWords(MRJob):

def mapper(self, _, line):
    cat, phrase, phraseid, sentiment = line.split(',')
    yield (cat, phraseid, sentiment), phrase

def reducer(self, keys, values):

    yield keys, list(values)

#Output: ["Train", "--", "2"] ["A series of escapades demonstrating the adage that    what is good for the goose", "A series", "A", "series"]

def mapper(self, keys, values):
    vectorizer = CountVectorizer(min_df=0)
    vectorizer.fit(values)
    x = vectorizer.transform(values)
    x=x.toarray()       
    yield keys, (x)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bagOfWords.run()
```

ValueError: empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stop words

Thank you for any help you guys can provide.

Answer (score 0):

The `CountVectorizer` is stateful: you need to fit the same one instance on the full dataset to build the vocabulary hence this is not amenable to parallel processing.

Instead you can use the `HashingVectorizer` which is stateless (no need to fit, you can call `transform` directly).